# Use JQuery to set the select option value and text from Array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I have a `select` box that I am getting `multiple` values from and storing them in an `Array`using `JQuery`.

I would like to know how I can then use the contents of this `Array` to populate `options` in another select box.

So currently I've got this:

```
 $('#addBtn').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        //Get the selected Items in the dropdown 1
        var selected = new Array();
        $('#compresult option:selected').each(function(){
            selected.push($(this).val() + " " + $(this).text());//Add to Array
        });

        //Update contents of dropdown 2  with the Array 
     });
```

My `HTML` for dropdown is :

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="contributors[]" id="compresult">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="3610">X</option>
    <option value="3605">Y</option>
    <option value="335">Z</option>
 </select>
```

If I select option X and Y my `selected` array in my `JS` Code outputs this:

```
Array [ "3610 X", "3605 Y" ]
```

How can I then use these values to populate another dropdown? i'm trying to implement an ADD/REMOVE from list functionality type thing.

EDIT: EXPECTED OUTPUT OF DROPDOWN 2

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="dropdown2" id="compresult">
        <option value="3610">X</option>
        <option value="3605">Y</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please add expected output (eg what the html of dropdown2 should look like)

Comment: @user574632 I've done that now

Comment: The id's must be unique, change the name of second select. I think it's a TYPO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just build the html string in your loop:

```
$('#addBtn').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //Get the selected Items in the dropdown 1
    var drop2html = '';
    $('#compresult option:selected').each(function(){
        drop2html += '<option value="' + $(this).val() + '">' + $(this).text() + '</option>';
    });

    $('#drop2').html(drop2html);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

ID should be unique `id="compresult">`

```
 $('#addBtn').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var selected = $('#compresult option:selected').clone(); // get the selected option and copy that element 
    $("#compresult1").html(selected); // insert into new dropdown list 

});
```

### [UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L9NFX/13/)

Comment: @Javacadabra .Do not think about anything , i think it is best solution compare to other one ,It may be very useful for searching users

Answer (score 0):

Change the `push` line to

```
selected.push([$(this).val(), $(this).text()]);
```

...so we have the option value and text held separately, not concatenated as one string.

Then, to create the new `select` (you don't say if you want to create a new one or populate an existing one - I'll assume the latter):

```
var other_sel = $('#other_select').empty();
$.each(selected, function(i, arr) {
    $('<option /', {value: arr[0], text: arr[1]}).appendTo(other_sel);
});
```